# Using NextIntlClientProvider always renders 404

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-intl

I do not know how to describe this. In the `app/[locale]/layout.tsx`, placing `<NextIntlClientProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>{children}</NextIntlClientProvider>` always causes the `not-found` page to be displayed.

Removing `NextIntlClientProvider` renders the page (though it breaks because `useTranslations` complains that no `NextIntlClientProvider` was provided).

Both `locale` and `messages` are valid; `locale` match the locales inside `middleware.ts` and `next.config.js`, and `messages` contains all expected strings.

The `onError` prop for `NextIntlClientProvider` does not get called at all, and there are no output to the console.

What is causing this? How to debug?

**NOTE:** this is using Next.js 14.1.3 App Router.

Comment: Do you call `notFound()` anywhere?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelbaset I have removed all call to `notFound()` in the project when trying to isolate the issue, so no. There are no error message, nothing. Removing the `NextIntlClientProvider`, the page renders just fine, except from the `useTranslations` issue.

Comment: A reproduction would help